# Assign a DateTime to Nullable<DateTime> in F#

Tags: casting, f#, type-conversion, nullable

I have some F# code where I need to update a field in a database record. I am using the Type Provider for SQL.  The table has a nullable datevalue field.  When I try to update the value of the date field to DateTime.UtcNow the compiler complains that "This expression was expected to have type Nullable<DateTime> but here has type DateTime".  How do I convert/cast from DateTime to Nullable<DateTime>.

My code currently looks something like follows:

```
for queryItem in queryResult do
    queryItem.CurrentDate <-  DateTime.UtcNow  // This gives compiler error as described above
```

Regards

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The comment by John Palmer above links to the solution.  One needs to use the System.Nullable constructor i.e.

```
queryItem.CurrentDate <- System.Nullable DateTime.UtcNow
```